# How to use two parameter in CommandArgument and extract it to use it in a query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following ASP.net page which displays the name and the last four ssn number with a button in a repeater:

```
<tr>
     <td><%# Eval("name").ToString() %></td>
     <td><%# Eval("ssn3").ToString() %></td>
     <td><asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name").ToString() + ", " + Eval("ssn3").ToString() %>' onclick="btnGeneratePDF_Click" /></td>
</tr>
```

In my code behind to evaluate the commandargument, I have a code like this:

```
    protected void btnGeneratePDF_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string[] ar = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
    MessageBox.Show(ar[0]);
    MessageBox.Show(ar[1]);
    this.writeData(ar[0], ar[1]);
}

public void writeData(string k, string c)
{
    Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
    Conn.Open();

    nameE = txtName.Text;

    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/fw9.pdf"));

    // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
    var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]"] = txtName.Text;

    sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_04_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_05_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_07_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField1[0]"] = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[0]"] = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[1]"] = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[2]"] = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[3]"] = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Requester's name and address (hard-coded)
    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_06_0_[0]"] = "Medical Group\n20 West Ave\nPurchase, NY 10001";

    var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

    PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-W9.pdf");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

`Error  1   No overload for 'btnGeneratePDF_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'   C:\Users\usrs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PDFForms\searchcreate.aspx  41`

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: `Button` click delegate expects an `EventArgs` parameters not a `CommandEventArgs`

Comment: To handle command sent by the button, subscribe to the Command event of the Repeater

Comment: If I change it to `EventArgs` I get the following error: `Error 1 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 'CommandArgument' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\usrs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PDFForms\searchcreate.aspx.cs 38 25 C:\...\PDFForms\`

Comment: Use parameterised queries!  You are wide open to SQL Injection, and you even have a column named SSN...

Comment: @Siyual Am I not using a parameterised queries?

Comment: @SiKni8 `WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'"; ` . . . No...

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnGeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Change `CommandEventArgs` to `EventArgs` in click event

Try this

```
protected void btnGeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Get the reference of the clicked button.
  Button button = (sender as Button);
  //Get the command argument
  string commandArgument = button.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: If I change it to `EventArgs` I get the following error: `Error 1 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 'CommandArgument' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\usrs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PDFForms\searchcreate.aspx.cs 38 25 C:\...\PDFForms\`

Comment: `sender` will be the button, cast and then query it's `CommandArgument` property.

Comment: What for? Why not handle Repeater's event instead? It provides Command Argument naturally

Comment: @Andrei: Good spot, indeed I very much doubt that this handler will even be wired up as is - I suggest you add an answer...

Comment: @Andrei Please give me an example I can work with :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Command Name field to store second param or use ASP:HiddenField, CustomProperty ect

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have this layout inside the `Repeater` control, here is how you should handle a command event.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1"
              OnItemCommand="btnGeneratePDF_Click"
              ...
```

They way `btnGeneratePDF_Click` is implemented it should work as is, you do not need to adjust anything. However I do recommend renaming it properly, and using `CommandName` also - that will prove useful if you would like to add more commands inside the repeater later.

One more side note. Notice that Repeater's ItemCommand event actually uses `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` class, which is a subclass of `CommandEventArgs`. If you walk down the path above you might want to change this as well in your method signature.

Comment: I changed by button to this: `<asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name").ToString() + ", " + Eval("ssn3").ToString() %>' />` and added the `OnItemCommand` in my repeater and how should I change the function for the btnGeneratorPDF_Click?

Comment: @SiKni8, in fact you do not need to change it, there is nothing specific there. Although I do not think you MessageBox calls will work

Comment: The MessageBox only works while running from VS so I figured it out :) What should I add in the button? no click event?

Comment: @SiKni8, no, you do not need to handle click event for the button in that case

Comment: Ok that is fixed I think... Now the query is running blank :/ I will open a new question and post a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform an command event into a click event.
The correct it should be:

```
<tr>
     <td><%# Eval("name").ToString() %></td>
     <td><%# Eval("ssn3").ToString() %></td>
     <td><asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name").ToString() + ", " + Eval("ssn3").ToString() %>' OnCommand="btnGeneratePDF_Command" /></td>
</tr>
```

When you create this new event, you will notice that the event parameter changes to CommandEventArgs.
The you can proceed with you code

Comment: The query is coming out empty now :/

Comment: The query that builds the controller?

Comment: I used a MessageBox to display the two variable I am passing and they are displayed correctly but columns are empty when the query is done :/

Comment: `sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";` I am not sure if it's producing anything.

Comment: Seems like if I have it like this: `sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "'"; // AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";` it works fine but if there are multiple entries, no matter what button is clicked, only the first row is used. For some reason adding the second argument causes my query to NOT work :/

Comment: You have to use while (reader.Read()) insted of if (reader.Read()).
You are only reading the first entry with the if statement

Comment: The IF works just fine because I am actually reading one row for each button click...